# How does RequireJS download a new script file?

Tags: requirejs

I'm trying to wrap my mind around RequireJS. I understand the modularity that it provides and the on-demand script loading.

My doubt was: how can a script download another script? I was wondering whether exists some API that allows custom JavaScript code to call another script download, or how other way would RequireJS use to accomplish that. But I've searched all around for this answer without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer only at [RequireJS source code](http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.17/comments/require.js). I’ve found that the `load` function, if the runtime environment is a browser, will create a `<script>` tag and put it in the `<head>` of the document, with the appropriate url in the `src` attribute. Check the `createNode` function also.

Once the tag is created and added to the document, the browser will then download the script file.